# Why does my hair particles grow on the other side of the vertex grouped mesh?

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups

I added hair particle system on my mesh using vertex groups but it seems it applies on the other side of the mesh rather than the area where I specified with vertex group.
[image]

[image]

As you can see it followed the vertex group but its on the other side of the mesh.
I'm aiming for a velcro type of hair particles on the vertex grouped area but I don't why the particles system is acting this way.
I'm using blender 3.0.0

Comment: Maybe try to flip the normals? Select all in Edit mode and Alt N > Flip Normals

Comment: Are you using a solidify modifier?

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka No I'm not using solidify modifier

Comment: @moonboots It worked!
Thank you, I didn't the normals were flipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip the normals: Select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Flip Normals*.